nginx gives django static status 200 inside docker, but it is not shown
I have a static directory in my nginx container and when I go to http://localhost/admin it gives me
nginx | 1.1.1.1 - - [10/Dec/2024:12:41:17 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 21544 "http://localhost/admin/login/? next=/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 

but it doesn’t show up, what’s the error? P.S
in developer mode in Networks I see loaded static, I cleared the cache, in my html there is {% load static %}
docker-compose:
  django:
    container_name: django
    build:
      context: django
    command: gunicorn -w 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 src.wsgi:application
    working_dir: /django/src
    volumes:
      - ./django:/django
      - static_volume:/django/src/static
    env_file:
      - django/.env
    depends_on:
      - django_postgres
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - static_volume:/static
    depends_on:
      - django
    environment:
      - NGINX_LOGGING_STDOUT=true

volumes:
  static_volume:

nginx.conf
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location /static/ {
            alias /static/;
            access_log /dev/stdout;
            error_log /dev/stderr debug;
        }

        location /favicon.ico {
            access_log off;
            return 204;
        }

        location ~* \.map$ {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django:9000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    }
}

settings.py
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'src/static/'

inside nginx container
bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint.d  docker-entrypoint.sh  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  static  sys  tmp  usr  var

inside static
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 Layer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    0 Dec  9 13:21 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 admin
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 django_extensions
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 leaflet
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 main
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec 10 12:01 rest_framework

I tried changing the paths in settings, explicitly specifying
DEBUG=True,

explicitly doing
python manage.py collectstatic

